# Remove file from git repo, but not from server

Tags: git, github, symlink

At some point in the past, a symlink media file has been added to a git repo I'm working on.  I want to remove it from the repo, delete the file locally, but not on the server the repo is deployed to (I would also not want to have to re-make the symlink).  `git update-index --assume-unchanged` does not appear to be persistent, and `git rm --cached` would kill the files on deploy.

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: What do you mean remove it from the repo? remove it from your local repository? and do it in such a way in  the next pull it doesn't re-appear or that if you push it won't push the deletion?

Comment: if you are not planning to modify the object intentionally then you can add it to your git.ignore file

Comment: Your local repo and the server repo are copies. You can have things locally that you don't push to the server (using gitignore) but you can't have things on the remote that you don't have locally.

Comment: @kabanus remove it from the repository, so I can have an actual media folder to work with, but keep the symlink on the server

Comment: @Artem it's already in the gitignore file but because the media file is in the repo it still tracks changes

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the live server isn't actually a git repo, but is deployed via deployhq

Comment: Than this is a `deployhq` question. What you want is for `deployhq` to add a file on top of your git. Change thequestion to make this clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing to what you want I found in `deployhq` [config files](https://support.deployhq.com/articles/advanced-settings/managing-config-files). This is good for any non-repo text file, but unfortunately this won't work for symlinks.

This may work:

1. first remove the symlink from the repo (git rm, commit, push/deploy).
2. `ssh` to the server where you deployed. Create the symbolic link there. If it's something in the repo you can add it to `.gitignore`, but you don't have to - it won't matter.

Now the server has the link, and it's unconnected to the repository so it will not exist in `github` or whatever you're using, or your local machine. It will only be a file on the server. The point is the **link should not be at all in the repo anywhere**, and **you need to create it manually on the server**.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is : no, there is no way to both :

1. delete a file from the repo
2. have a raw `git pull` *not* delete the file on disk on a clone

If your deployment process starts with `git pull` on your production machine, you will have to take some extra action to re-create the symlink on this machine.

---

I don't know how deployhq works : I imagine you have a way to code "and please execute this script/list of actions after deploying the code", this list of actions should include "add the symlink".